# Python Selenium Element Not Found

Tags: python, selenium

When element not found should print : not found, but i got error :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='q']"}
```

Here is my script and the element 'search' doesn't exist

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\SAMSUNG\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://facebook.com')
search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='q']")
time.sleep(15)
if search:
    time.sleep(15)
    print('found')
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='q']").send_keys('test')
else:
    print('not found')
    pass
```

Didn't work because we can't do len to element ( we can do it only to elements with an s )

Comment: Try `matches = find_elements_by_xpath(...)`, check `len(matches)`, then do `matches[0].send_keys(...)`

Comment: this will works, but the element i'm looking to see if it exists or not is only 1 element so should be find_element_by_xpath

Comment: You missed the whole point of `matches[0]`

Comment: @SarahGuegan If you have new issue then please submit new question instead of changing current question so drastically. Users might be confused because answers and comments have nothing to do with updated question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the below code and let me know if it works.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
action = ActionChains(driver)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\SAMSUNG\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get('https://facebook.com')

try:
    search = wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='q']")))
    print('Element Found')
    action.move_to_element(search).send_keys('test').perform()
except:
    print("Element not Found")
```

Comment: it works when the element is not displayed ( print : element not found ) . But when the element is displayed , it print not found too

Comment: catching every exception isn't considered good practice. With that, you also catch a kill command from os or a KeyboardInterrupt (Ctrl+C). Usually you want to know, when something bad happens. See PEP8 for more infos. try catching exception selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException. Don't see however how that is not working.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need `len` and neither the `else` block.
You can simply check if `loginform` is True/False i.e. if `loginform` is identified successfully then it will return True and execute the `if` block.

Updated to use try-except structure.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

try:
    time.sleep(3)
    search = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='q']")
    print('found')
    time.sleep(3)
    search.send_keys('test')
except NoSuchElementException: 
    print('not found')
    pass
```

Comment: I did both if loginform and   if driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='email']"):

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@name='email']"}

Comment: Add another `time.sleep` before you identify `loginform = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='email']")`
Once you are comfortable enough with your script, consider replacing `time.sleep` with `WebDriverWait` - it's a more robust way of waiting between actions.

Comment: still nothing, i updated my issue for easy understanding

Comment: Place that first time.sleep BEFORE identifying loginform, or, as per your new code, before 'search=...',  and after the driver.get line.

Comment: I tried it too. the element 'search' does not exist on that page. You can run the script on ur laptop to better understand it. I want it to know that the element doesn't exist and to pass it

Comment: Updated to use `try-except` blocks.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't found a tag "input" with name="q" on facebook. Not sure however, if the other can confirm. It would be nice to have an example webpage (put driver.page_source into a file) where it should be there.